# Cannot access Heroku rails console from terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-console, heroku-cli

I am working on a ruby-on rails application, trying to access the Heroku rails console for my production database. The current Gems I am using (that I think could be related) are: Bootsnap, Bootstrap, Devise, Carrierwave, figaro, and fog-aws.

When I run `heroku run rails console` I get this error:

```
        31: from /app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
        30: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        29: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        28: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        27: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        26: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        25: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        24: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        23: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        22: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        21: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        20: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        19: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:95:in `perform'
        18: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:14:in `require_application_and_environment!'
        17: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4/lib/rails/command/actions.rb:22:in `require_application!'
        16: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        15: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        14: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        13: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        12: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        11: from /app/config/application.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
         9: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         8: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
         7: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
         6: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
         5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/carrierwave-2.0.2/lib/carrierwave.rb:59:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/carrierwave-2.0.2/lib/carrierwave.rb:60:in `<module:CarrierWave>'
         3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:58:in `load_missing_constant'
         2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `rescue in load_missing_constant'
         1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:8:in `without_bootsnap_cache'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/active_support.rb:79:in `block in load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Rails::Railtie (NameError)
```

After a bit of research there is a few things that I tried.

to make sure I was logged in  I ran `heroku login` which *should* prompt a browser window to pop up for the CLI sign in, however that would stay in a constant loop not doing anything. With that I had to sign in with `sudo heroku login -i` and sign in through the terminal, which worked fine.

after that I found someone on here with a slightly similar issue that got around this hangup with `heroku run bash` and `rails c`. while I was able to run bash, rails c still spit out the same error above.

to check my loose ends I updated all my gems and the rails version and made sure that the updated versions were saved in the Gemfile as well as the Gemfile.lock.

It is also worth noting that my local app as well as my Heroku app both are fully functional otherwise, and  I can access the usual rails console.

any insight will be greatly appreciated, thanks ahead of time.

Comment: can you please check ruby and rails version installed on heroku and compare to your project versions?